# How can I substitute quotation marks in Excel with SUBSTITUTE formula?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have worksheet where I need named ranges to correspond to the contents of another cell.  The text in the cell is something like:

```
Partitions w Studs 16" oc
```

Named ranges cannot have spaces, or most importantly, special characters like ".  So, the range is named the following:

```
PartitionswStuds16oc
```

To change the former into a reference to the latter in the worksheet, I can handle removing the spaces with the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1," ","")
```

I cannot, however, substitute the `"` because the double-quotation mark is used to specify text in the formula.  Excel can't parse the following formula, as expected:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1," ",""),""","")
```

Any tips on how to get around this?  I know I could change the text to say `16-in.` instead of `16"`, but I want to keep it as my client requested if possible.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`""""` escapes a `"`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1," ",""), """", "")
```

Answer (score 15):

Try using `CHAR(34)` as substitute for ":

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,CHAR(34),"")
```

Answer (score 3):

To use double qutoes within a quoted string, just double them. In your case, this results in four consecutive double quotes:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"""","")
```