# Special character replacing

Tags: excel, replace, special-characters

Is it possible to remove the `"` character using an Excel formula?

I tried the REPLACE function like this

```
REPLACE(<sometext>, """, "")
```

and this

```
REPLACE((<sometext>, char(34), "")
```

but it doesn't work.

NB: I am using the Polish version of Excel, so it is probable, that the syntax is different than in the English version. For example, in Polish formulas we use `;` instead of `,` as argument separator.

Comment: Question previously answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695169/how-can-i-substitute-in-excel-with-substitute-formula

Answer (score 6):

The quotation mark character `"` must be represented by two of them `""` when it's inside a string, to revolve the ambiguity between this "textual" quotation mark and the "code" quotation marks that delimit the beginning and end of your string.

In short, the right formula to remove all `"` from the text in A1 is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","")
```

with emphasis on the fact that the `old_text` argument has to be `""""` (four quotes) and not `"""` (three quotes) as you wrote in your question.

And maybe `SUBSTITUTE` is called Replace in the Polish edition? Anyhow, you have to use the Polish equivalent of `SUBSTITUTE` and whatever argument separator is appropriate (`;` or `,`).

Answer (score 2):

Replace doesn't work the way, you want it to.
Use `SUBSTITUTE`.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(34), "-")
```

OR use `;` as separator for your example

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1; CHAR(34); "-")
```